# Get Facebook Ad Accounts Data into dropdown option list via AppScript

Tags: google-apps-script

I have successfully retrieved Ad Accounts data through this function makeRequest. I can see the result in the appsscript execution log -

console.log(data.adaccounts.data[0].account_id); //26123718

I have stored the data over here

const data = JSON.parse(response);

How can I fetch the Ad account IDs into a drop down list as shown in the HTML

```
<select id="select">
   
</select>
```

```
    function makeRequest() {
      
      // get the Facebook Service
      const facebookService = getFacebookService();
      
      // get the access token
      const access_token = facebookService.getAccessToken();
      console.log(access_token);
      
    
      //set up the API Endpoint
    
      const base = 'https://graph.facebook.com/v10.0/';
      
      const endpoint = 'me?&fields=adaccounts';
    
      const url = base + endpoint;
      console.log(url);
    
      const params = {
    
        headers: {
    
          Authorization: 'Bearer ' + access_token
        }
        
      }
      
      const response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url,params);
      console.log(response);
    
      const data = JSON.parse(response);
      console.log(data);
    
      console.log(data.adaccounts.data[0].account_id);
    
       
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your html file, you can use `google.script.run.withSuccessHandler()` to call a function in Code.gs and if the function returns successfully it will pass the data to the callback function.

**Example:**

**Code.gs**

```
function doGet() {
  return HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('Index').evaluate();
}
 
//GET DATA FROM GOOGLE SHEET AND RETURN AS AN ARRAY
function makeRequest(){
  //Insert your function that will fetch data from facebook ads here

  //For example the account IDs are "12345","32456", "23423" 
  var account_id = ["12345","32456", "23423"];
  return account_id;
}
 
//INCLUDE JAVASCRIPT AND CSS FILES
function include(filename) {
  return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile(filename)
      .getContent();
}
```

**Index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top"> 
    <?!= include('JavaScript'); ?>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container">
      <br>
      <select id="select">
      </select>
    </div>  
  </body>
</html>
```

**JavaScript.html**

```
<script>
  // This will call makeRequest() function in the Code.gs and 
  // pass the data to appendToDropDown function 
  google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(appendToDropDown).makeRequest();
 
  //This function will add option to select tag 
  function appendToDropDown(ids){
    var select = document.getElementById('select');
    for (var i=0; i<ids.length; i++) {      
      var opt = document.createElement('option');     
      opt.text = ids[i]
      select.add(opt);
    }
  }
</script>
```

**Output:**

[image]

### Reference:

- [Class google.script.run](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/reference/run)

Comment: I want to create a loop:            

This doesn't work. Can you guide me where I am going wrong?

`function appendToDropDown(id)
{   var select = document.getElementById('select');
    //you can create a loop here if the data contains more than 1 items    
    for (var i=0;i<data.adaccounts.data.length;i++) {
     var opt = document.createElement('option');
    opt.value = id;
    opt.innerHTML = id;
    select.appendChild(opt);
    }`